# odoo calculate 2 fields with compute

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I have this 2 fields which is I want to calculate using compute

```
_columns = {
    'feb_target':fields.float('Februari Target'),
    'apr_target':fields.float('April Target'),
    'ytd':fields.float('YTD', compute='_computeytd'),
}

@api.depends('feb_target', 'apr_target')
def _computeytd(self):
    for record in self:
        record.ytd = record.feb_target + record.apr_target
```

But the result is 0.

What should I do? Thank you

Comment: Is it Odoo 10 or Odoo 8? I wouldn't use `_columns` for field definitions in those versions anymore.

Comment: I'm using odoo 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow that took me back to my beginnings.

Old API fields defined in `_columns` should use `fields.function` for computed fields. But i prefer to use the "new" API when possible. And your code looks like fully done by yourself, so it is possible.

```py
from odoo import api, fields, models

class YourClass(models.Model):

    feb_target = fields.Float('Februari Target')
    apr_target = fields.Float('April Target')
    ytd = fields.Float('YTD', compute='_compute_ytd')

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('feb_target', 'apr_target')
    def _compute_ytd(self):
        for record in self:
            record.ytd = record.feb_target + record.apr_target
```